# Materialize css not rendering toast

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, notice, materialize

I'm trying to use the toast component from materialize.css to render flash messages. I'm modified my layout to do so but I'm not getting any toasts.

#### app/view/layouts/application.html.slim

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title
      | A beautiful Site
    = stylesheet_link_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi"
    = csrf_meta_tags
    meta[name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"]
    = analytics_init unless Rails.env.test?
  body
    .row
      = render partial: "elements/navbar"
      - flash.each do |_key, msg|
        javascript:
          Materialize.toast(msg, 5000);
    .row
      .container.col.s10
        = yield
      .meta.col.s2
        = render partial: 'elements/ads'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me...

```
    - if flash.any?
      javascript:
        $(function(){Materialize.toast("#{notice}", 5000);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is attempting to use the Javascript variable "msg" which does not exist.  You should be able to verify this in your browser's console.

You need to use the Rails variable for this to work:

```
- flash.each do |_key, msg|
  javascript:
    Materialize.toast("#{msg}", 5000);
```

Make sure you quote the variable as well.

Comment: I'm still not getting any messages.

Comment: @AntarrByrd you must escape the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're calling Materialize.toast(), before the page & javascript files have finished loading. The best way to fix this is to wrap your your javascript call with

> $(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE GOES HERE })

Try this

> `- flash.each do |name, msg|
>    :javascript
>       $(function(){Materialize.toast("#{msg}", 10000);});`